# Downloading a deployed app packaged from a Windows Phone device

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I've recently had some data loss. I would like to be able to download my compiled app package that I have deployed on my phone. I haven't been able to download the app package that I have uploaded in the store (as they are nearly identical), so if there is a way to do that, that would be amenable as well.

Is there a way to download the app package from a device or from the Store page?

Edit: I should note that by "Store Page" I mean "App Submission Page".

Comment: Do you mean the .xap file?  I know you can download manually from the store's application page.  Not sure about the App submission page though.

Comment: Is that true for Windows Phone apps?

Comment: Yeah.  I will put it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the xap file manually from the application's store page.  For example, I have a game that I haven't updated in forever (forgive me) :)

[Number Munchers XL](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/number-munchers-xl/59f7dee4-2171-4cff-9828-2a4be08833ff)

---

Scroll down to the very bottom on the left side of the page, and you will see

> Download and install manually
>   Learn more

Click on that and you should be greeted with a XAP file download.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! using the XAP link got me my `.appxbundle`.